# The pullback of a transitive relation is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $S$ is a relation on $B$. Define a relation $R$ on $A$ by:

$R = \{(x, y) \in A \times  A : (f(x), f(y)) \in S\}$

Prove that if $S$ is transitive then so is $R$.

**Solution, given by professor:**

Let $x, y, z \in A$.

Assume $_xR_y$ and $_yR_z$. Then $_{f(x)}S_{f(y)}$ and $_{f(y)}S_{f(z)}$.

Since $S$ is transitive, $_{f(x)}S_{f(z)}$.

By denition of $R$, this means $_xR_z$.

**What I don't understand**

$R = \{(x, y) \in A \times  A : (f(x), f(y)) \in S\}$

Does the $:$ in this relation mean $(x, y) \in A \times  A $ $iff$ $(f(x), f(y)) \in S$ ?

I'm unfamiliar with this notation, and am not sure I fully understand the relationship between the two relations. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon : inside set brackets means "such that". Here, $(x,y)\in$$R$ iff $(x,y)\in$$A$$\times$$A$ and $(f(x),f(y))\in$$S$.